# What's a Multiple?

Tags: arithmetic

A quick question-Something that I learned that I forgot throughout the years.

If a question asked you for a multiple of 9 and 12, which would be less than 40, would "36" be an answer, as both 9 and 12 can multiply to get 36, yet it fits under the criteria for being under 40?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are correct with your reasoning. [Multiples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_%28mathematics%29) of $9$ are of the form $9m$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, the set of integers.